# Correct Permissions for WWW Data

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, web

I keep coming back to perfect web-based permissions, I've done it a few ways. This post isn't as complex as it is a little long, I wanted to provide some samples.

I've searched far and wide but I am wondering if there is a de-facto standard. Thank you for your time.

**Q: Can anyone please advise me the best approach according to the basic Permission Goals below?**

- **Permission Goal:**

  - Prevent `0777` mode
  - Default group `www-data` is sticky
  - Default user as `myself` is stick *(If possible, I don't think a default exists in setfacl)*
- **Cliff Notes**

  - Using: `Ubuntu 16.04` and `16.10` *(Desktop Versions at the Moment)*

### $ chmod g+rws

I have set this prior, I do wonder why this **highlights my file an orange color, it concerns me**. The goal was to keep current and new files as `www-data`.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rws /var/www  # <-- s or S?
```

The above works for the most part but **I have read it's bad to use**, why? So I tried `setfacl`.

## $ setfacl

Here I `setfacl`, the problem is that it will make all current files `+x` for the user, I don't want that.

```
# For Current Files | User/Group
sudo setfacl -Rm u:myself:rwx /var/www
sudo setfacl -Rm g:ww-data:rwx /var/www

# For Future Files | User/Group
sudo setfacl -Rmd u:myself:rwx /var/www
sudo setfacl -Rm g:www-data:rwx /var/www
```

## .bashrc setfacl files/dirs separately

So a crazy idea I had was to make a `.bashrc` function It's not fully correct yet, but you get the idea.

```
function facl_file() {
    echo "(+) Set ACL for $USER:www-data rw [Files Only, Persist]"

    # Files cannot have defaults -d permissions
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        echo "  Setting $file"
        # Default Mode: RW
        mode="rw"

        # If Executable, Add RWX
        if [[ -x "$file" ]]; then
            mode="rwx"
        fi
        sudo setfacl  -m u:$USER:$mode $file
        sudo setfacl  -m g:www-data:$mode $file
    done < <(find $CREATE -type f -print0)
    echo "(+) Done with Files"
}

function facl_dir() {
    echo "(+) Set ACL for $USER:www-data rwx [Directories Only, Persist]"
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
        echo "  Setting $dir"
        sudo setfacl  -m u:$USER:rwx $dir
        sudo setfacl -dm u:$USER:rwx $dir
        sudo setfacl  -m g:www-data:rwx $dir
        sudo setfacl -dm g:www-data:rwx $dir
    done < <(find $CREATE -type d -print0)
    echo "(+) Done with Directories"
}
```

The goal of the above was to prevent `Directories` from losing the `+x`, and prevent files that were not `+x` from becoming it.

---

Any advice would be appreciated if I am going the wrong way about this. I can't seem to find a good "Sticky Standard" that feels right.

Comment: I believe `rwx` should be `rwX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize this post was still here, so I would answer my own Q. Try using `X` instead of `x`. I would do it with a test folder first:

```
cd ~; mkdir test; touch test/{default,run.sh};chmod +x test/run.sh

# Ensure this fellow is in here!
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER 

sudo setfacl -R -m g:www-data:rwX ~/test
sudo setfacl -Rd -m g:www-data:rwX ~/test
sudo getfacl ~/test
```

This will set keep the folder x and run.sh x -- the only change visible is the + at the end as in: `-rwxrwxr-x+` - it just means it has addtl `facl set.

Hope this helps.